# Ubuntu 13.04 no menu bars

Tags: unity, 13.04, menu-bar, ubuntu-tweak, ccsm

I just played with Ubuntu 13.04 on my old netbook. I tried some configurations, installed Xubuntu and Gnome to find out, which desktop environment runs best.

Now I want to stay with Unity. But I noticed, that in most of the applications (like terminal, or ccsm) the top menu bar for windows is gone. I can see the top menu bar from the application itself on top of my display. But when I try to move a window around, the bar kinda disappears. And afterwards, I can't move the window anymore.

I know that I played a lot with Unity Tweak and CCSM to figure out the best settings. But I can't remember what I've done wrong.

So any help is appreciated!

Here is a screenshot. As you can see, the terminal "hides" under the top menu bar, and I can't move the window. The same thing with the CCSM window.

[image: Ubuntu window no menu bar]

Comment: can you give a visual example (via scr shots)?

Comment: I've added a screenshot

Comment: Is CCSM->Window decoration disabled?

Comment: great, that's it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CCSM enable Window decoration option